# cannot create react element using es6

Tags: reactjs

i have this code so far and trying to use ES6 syntax to create buttons onto webpage

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button>{this.props.text}</button>
  };
};

class Element extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomButton text="I" />
        <CustomButton text="know" />
        <CustomButton text="React!" />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

ReactDOM.render(
  Element,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

however nothing is being created on the web page.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the render part wrong. You are defining a component there so, it should be like that:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Element />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Your `Element` is not a JSX element actually, it is a class component so you should use it properly.

```
const foo = <div>Foo</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  foo,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

This works because `foo` is an element, it is not a class or a functional component.

[See for more.](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)